Mystery Device on my Automated Gate Controller Box (on Nice Apollo 1500 gate opener)
We have an automated gate Nice Apollo 1500 gate opener with an Apollo 635/636 control board and a LiftMaster RF controller.
There appears to be a key switch on the outside that is disconnected. Above the key switch is a plug and I can't figure out what it is.
I took it apart and it's just a piece of plastic. I'm super curious: what is this?




It looks like a push button switch.

I agree -- just looked it up https://apollogateopeners.com/store/apollo-1119-control-box-push-button-switch.html thanks!

it does not look like just a piece of plastic ... a metal component is clearly visible

It was a pushbutton switch, and that could be seen in the assembled picture.
Depending on your reassembly skills, it might or might not ever be one again.
Wiring to it is unclear in the picture, but may also be cut on at least one side, making it "also disconnected" - function of the point it's connected to on the control board is not documented in any of the easily found web-pages trying to sell you one that I've looked at so far (no user manual, installers manual, or input/output diagram for the board found. That documentation may exist, I just haven't found it if it does.)

Here’s a link to the manual.
https://apollogateopeners.com/store/pdf/1500_1600-install-update.pdf. Hope it helps

It’s the push button switch that manually opens the gate if your keypad doesn’t work.
Here’s a link to the manual.
https://apollogateopeners.com/store/pdf/1500_1600-install-update.pdf. Hope it helps
